# Paranthesis closure in Geany for c++

Tags: indentation, geany, auto-indent, geany-plugin

After typing

```
int func(){
```

And pressing enter I'm getting like this , since I have enabled auto close plugin

```
 int func(){
      //cursor stays here }
```

But what i need is

```
int func(){
     //cursor stays here
   }
```

I'm able to achieve the required indentation by changing snippets.conf, but I have to press c and Tab, where

```
c=%brace_open%%cursor%%brace_close%
brace_open={\n\t
brace_close=\n}\n
```

Auto-close plugin settings:

[image: Auto-close plugin settings]

is there any other way of achieving ?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to figure out how to get exactly what you've indicated, but the [Autoclose plugin](https://plugins.geany.org/autoclose.html) can get close. Typing `int func(){` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> gives the following, where the `|` character represents the cursor location:

```
int func(){
    |
}
```

**EDIT:**

My Autoclose settings are as shown below. But that turns out not to be the whole story. See after the image for more.

[image: Autoclose Configure Plugins dialog]

While looking into this some more, I discovered some *strange* behavior. I don't know if it's at the root of your problem or not, but it's maybe something to consider.

Autoclose worked as I described when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the main keyboard, but *not* when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keypad, with or without <kbd>NumLock</kbd> enabled. In the latter case, I got the same result you did.

I normally use an antique IBM Model M keyboard, so to eliminate any chance of the problem being caused by the keyboard itself, I tried a modern USB keyboard with keypad. The results were exactly the same.

Having a suspicion as to what was happening, and since it's open source, I pulled down the [Autoclose source code](https://plugins.geany.org/downloads.html) and took a look. And found...

```
static gboolean
auto_close_chars(
    AutocloseUserData *data,
    GdkEventKey       *event)
{
    ...
    else if (ch == GDK_Return)
    {
        return improve_indent(sci, editor, pos);
    }
    ...
}
```

A general search for `GDK_Return` turned up [gdkkeysyms.h](https://github.com/tindzk/GTK/blob/master/gdk/gdkkeysyms.h) that defines all of the GDK key codes. In that, there's `GDK_Return` and also `GDK_KP_Enter`, where "KP" means "keypad".  Since Autoclose doesn't recognize `GDK_KP_Enter`, it'll fail to respond to pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keypad.

So, if you're using a full keyboard with keypad, it *should* work ok so long as <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the main keyboard is being used. On the other hand, If you're using a laptop where there's only one <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, all bets are off.

Comment: i'm also using Autoclose plugin, but still not able to achieve , can you please see the Auto-close plugin settings image attached in the main post and suggest the changes @David Yockey

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://plugins.geany.org/autoclose.html for autoclose plugin. This will solve your problem.

In Linux you can directly install it by
`sudo apt-get install geany-plugin-autoclose`